# Do you need to leave import lines in?

Tags: python-3.x

Do you need to leave import lines in? For example:

If I do

```html
from random import randrange
```

I'm very new to python and when I take that line out my code does not work. Im not sure if there is a work around to that or if it need to stay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `randrange` function somewhere in your code - you must have that import statement as it brings this function to your code namespace so you are able to call it.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the feed back!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built in module, you have to import it. Importing it simply allows you to use the classes and functions of the "random" module. Without importing them, there's no function imported and it'll give you error.